# ffmpeg related: [NULL @ 00000000000a9500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇôI' ΓÇôI: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running the command

> "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\ffmpeg" -framerate 24 –I BWW_%03d.png output_24.mp4
>   ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)

and I get the above error. i.e.

[NULL @ 00000000000a9500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇôI'
ΓÇôI: Invalid argument

I get the same issue when I run the ffmpqg installed from the ffmpeg.org download site as well.

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you need to escape the percent sign by doubling:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\ffmpeg" -framerate 24 –I BWW_%%03d.png output_24.mp4
```